# Spring JPA with Hibernate Persistence provider and setting javax.persistence.schema-generation properties

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, derby

I am using Spring JPA with Hibernate as the persistence provider and Derby as the database. (Specifically, the version of jars are Spring version 4.3.4, Hibernate Entity Manager version 5.2.10 and Derby 10.13.1.1).

I want to check the correct approach for

1. The schema generation in the JPA properties.
2. How to use the schema generated from step 1 to create the database schema.

(**Note this is not a Spring Boot application.**)

My application config file is this:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.repository"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>org.model</value>
            <value>org.repository</value>
            <value>org.service</value>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:C:\\tmp\\testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="test"/>
    <property name="password" value="test"/>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.repository"></jpa:repositories>
```

For step (1), my investigation and testing suggests that it's possible to set the persistence schema generation inside the jpaProperties property as follows:

```
<prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action">create</prop>
<prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target">create.sql</prop>
```

This will generate a create.sql file. For step (2), I used

```
<prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source">script</prop>
<prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source">create.sql</prop>
<prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">create</prop>
```

However do I need to still set create=true in the URL jdbc:derby:C:\tmp\testdb? Do the above lines for javax.persistence.schema-generation assume the database has been created?

Comment: I can create the database via a command line as well with Derby, e.g. java -Dij.database=jdbc.derby:C:\tmp\testdb;create=true org.apache.derby.tools ij.   I wanted to check schema-generation is limited to just creating the schema _after_ the DB is created.

Comment: There's no harm to specify `create=true`; Derby allows you to connect to an already-existing database even if you specify `create=true` in the JDBC Connection URL. Think of it as "create if not exists".

Comment: @BryanPendleton how does the use of create=true work with javax.persistence.schema-generation?  Does JPA standardize the creation of the schema only?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know much about JPA. Just trying to help with the Derby part.